# SBCL and LangUtils

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf

Has anyone got langutils working with sbcl?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, my email is eslick @ the mit media lab.  I have a deployed web application using langutils to stem text into Montezuma for full text indexing running on SBCL.  I've been meaning to take another stab at packaging and releasing langutils; perhaps in a month or two.  Love to have your feedback.

Comment: I had problems getting load.lisp to detect the dependencies, particularly port. I would appreciate it if you could assume a dir structure and explain how to configure load.lisp. (Assume that libraries are installed using asdf-install into ~).You could also assume that reader knows jack about asdf :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask Ian Eslick himself? He'd probably be quite interested in any problems you experienced with langutils and SBCL.